# Dealing with Heteroskedasticity in Estimated Dependent Variable model

Tags: panel-data, standard-error, heteroscedasticity, white-test, wls

I work on my research in finance concerning pricing of green bonds and I am running a two stage model.

**Stage 1** regression is an **unbalanced panel fixed effects estimation**. For each of my 100 green bonds in the sample, I compare its daily ask yield to an ask yield of a similar conventional bond and estimate the difference while controlling for the difference in their liquidity:

```
(yield.green - yield.conventional) ~ (liquidity.green - liquidity.conventional)
```

I am particularly interested in the individual effects captured by the intercepts - for each of my 100 green bonds, I save the estimated individual fixed effect which tells me if that bond sells for a higher price than its conventional counterpart. I call this fixed effect a "green premium".

**Stage 2** model is on **OLS regression of "green premium" on bond's characteristics**, e.g.:

```
green.premium ~ maturity + issue.amount + currency + sector
```

**Now the problematic part comes:**
Since my dependent variable "green premium" is an estimate coming from the Stage 1 regression, I need to deal with heteroskedasticity, although Breusch Pagan test does not reveal any signs of heteroskedasticity.

Is any of these two remedies a good solution for my case:

1. Use **Weighted Least Squares** - for this case, shall I use the inverse of the squared standard error of the indivudual fixed effects from Stage 1 - 1/(SE^2)- as the weightes?
2. Use **White's SE**?